# guardar datos de formulario dinamico

Tags: php, javascript

Buen día espero y me puedan ayudar a resolver esta duda ya que soy nueva en esto. Estoy desarrollando un formulario para generar encuestas dinámicamente, en el formulario se pueden agregar preguntas,  cada pregunta se le puede agregar una cantidad indefinida de opciones como muestra la siguiente imagen.

[image]

Cada `input` padre (pregunta), tiene campos hijo (opciones) que también se agregan dinámicamente, así que tuve que agregar una variable para asignarme numeración a los campos padre (preguntas), ya que de esa manera puedo indicarle a cada hijo a que grupo de preguntas pertenece, sino al momento de agregar una opción a una segunda pregunta siempre la agregaba en la primera de la misma forma la momento de eliminar preguntas o una opción específica.

Mi pregunta es: como imprimir los datos de ese formulario dinámico en otra hoja.php
La intente con `foreach`  y `for` y no me da resultado, ya que necesito guardar en una BD la información.

El código la tengo de la siguiente manera:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Calendario</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="nuevo.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
  .col-md-12.fieldwrapper {
    margin-bottom: 2%;
  }

  .valor {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
  }

  .opcion {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }

  .fieldname {
    width: 85%;
    display: inline;
  }

  .cuerpo {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 5%;
    box-shadow: 10px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47);
  }
  /*  .new{
                  margin-left: 1.5%;
                }*/

  .remove {
    margin-left: 1%;
  }

  .subfield .remove {
    margin-top: 1%;
  }

  .btn-success {
    background: #00541c;
    border-color: #00541c;
  }

  .subfield {
    margin-top: 1%;
  }
</style>

<body style="background:#d6d6d6;">


  <script type="text/javascript">
    //script para agregar los formulario dinamicos  en el div que tiene la id llamada buildyourform cada vez que le da clic en el boton que tiene como  id add
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#add").click(function() {

        //agrega el primer gripo de la pregunta
        var intId = $("#buildyourform  div").length + 1;
        var fieldWrapper = $("<div  class = \"form-group\" class =\"col-md-10 fieldwrapper\" role=\"list\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
        var fName = $("<input type=\"text\" name = \" pregunta" + intId + "\" class=\"fieldname form-control\" placeholder=\" Preguna\" required />");
        var subWrapper = $("<fieldset id=\"subwrapper" + intId + "\"/>");

        var newButton = $("<button type=\"button\" class=\"new btn btn-success btn-sm\" id=\"new" + intId + "\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-plus\"></span></button");
        newButton.click(function() {

          //grupo para las opiones
          var Id = $("#subwrapper" + intId + " aside").length + 1;

          var subfield = $("<aside class =\"col-md-12 subfield\" id=\"subfield" + Id + "\"/>");
          var Name = $("<input type=\"text\" name =\"opcion" + Id + "" + intId + "\" class=\"opcion form-control\" placeholder=\" Opción\" required />");
          var value = $("<input type=\"number\" name = \"valor" + Id + "" + intId + "\" class=\"valor form-control\" placeholder=\" Valor\"  required />");

          //elimina una opcion espesifica
          var removeButton1 = $("<button type=\"button\" class=\"remove btn btn-danger btn-sm\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-trash\"></span></button");

          removeButton1.click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
          });

          subfield.append(Name);
          subfield.append(value);
          subfield.append(removeButton1);
          subfield.append(subdato);

          $("#subwrapper" + intId).append(subfield);

        });

        //elimina una pregunta espesifica
        var removeButton = $("<button type=\"button\" id=\"remove\" class=\"remove btn btn-danger btn-sm\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-trash\"></span></button");
        removeButton.click(function() {
          $(this).parent().remove();
        });

        fieldWrapper.append(fName);
        fieldWrapper.append(newButton);
        fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
        fieldWrapper.append(subWrapper);
        fieldWrapper.append(dato);

        $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
      });


      $(".remove").click(function() {

        //alert("hola");
        $(this).parent().remove();

      });

    });
  </script>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="col-md-10 cuerpo">
      <center>
        <h3>Nueva encuesta</h3>
      </center>
      <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="guardaEncuesta.php" target="_blank">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12" role="listitem">

          <input type="text" name="titulo" class="form-control" placeholder="Título" required>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="encabezado" required placeholder="Descripción de la encuesta"></textarea>
          <select name="area" class="form-control" required>
                <option value = "">Selecciona un Área dirigida</option>
                <option value = "1">Direccion de carreras</option>
                <option value = "1">Planeacion</option>
                <option value = "1">Control escolar</option>
              </select>

          <select name="dirigido" class="form-control" required>
                <option value = "">Selecciona  a quien va dirigida</option>
                <option value = "1">Profesores</option>
                <option value = "2">Alumnos</option>
                <option value = "3">Administrativos</option>
                <option value = "4">Profesores y administrativos</option>
                <option value = "5">General</option>
              </select>
        </div>

        <aside>
          <button type="button" class="add btn btn-success" id="add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Nueva pregunta</button>
        </aside>

        <div class="form-group col-md-12" role="listitem">

          <fieldset id="buildyourform">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="guardar" class="btn btn-success" value="Guardar">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

En la hoja **guardar.php** tengo el siguiente código 
solamente puedo recibir los datos estáticos y las preguntas, pero las opciones de cada pregunta no logran imprimirse.

```
<?php
require("../conexion.php");

if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){

$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$encabezado = $_POST['encabezado'];
$area = $_POST['area'];
$dirige = $_POST['dirigido'].'<br>';

$p = $_POST['numero'];

for ($i=1; $i <=$p; $i++) {

        $pregunta = $_POST["pregunta$i"];

         echo $pregunta.'<br>';



        }
        echo "<br>";    
}
?>
```

espero y puedan ayudarme :(, Gracias!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fx2f4ipqipoifj0/formulario_dinamico.rar?dl=0 igual aqui esta el ejemplo

Comment: ¿que tienes en el archivo [guardaEncuesta.php]?

Comment: var dato = $("<input type=\"hidden\" name = \"numero\" class=\"fieldname form-control\" value=\""+intId+"\" required />");
 que se encuencontraba en el script me servia como referencia para saber cuantas preguntas existe en el formulario y poder enviar recibirlo como $_post['numero'] y poder recorrerlo en el for, intente acerlo con las opcions pero no me dio resultado

Comment: si ya me di cuenta

Comment: Hola, tienes que recoger los datos como lista (array) ya cuando los tengas si puedes hacer el insert normalmente

Comment: hola ByGroxD, lo intenraré gracias

Comment: si quieres te comparto un ejemplo sencillo?

Comment: si es de la siguiente manera: foreache ($_POST as $Key => $value){ no me servirá de muecho porque necesito guardar informacion en varias tablas y necesito tener las variables} pero si existe otra forma con ese mismo metodo me yudarias mucho :D

Comment: Listo, ahi te deje un ejemplo con nombres y apellidos dinamicos

Comment: Me gustaría que me ayuden con el mismo tema o si acabaste el proyecto me asesores en como hacer la encuesta gracias

Answer (score 1):

la manera correcta de recibir un formulario dinamico es mediante listado `Array` en php hay distintas maneras de recoger un Array en mi caso lo hago de la siguiente manera

lo envio atravez de un input con determinado name y los corchetes de la siguiente forma

```
<input class="form-control validate[required]" name="nombre[]" />
```

estos corchetes me indican que es un array en caso de php no tiene necesidad de tener un numero incrementándose dentro de los corchetes, no es necesario

ya en php lo recoges de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach (array_keys($_POST['nombre']) as $key) {
  $nombre = $_POST['nombre'][$key];

  echo "Nombre: $nombre"."<br>";
}
```

Soy un poco malo explicando sin embargo te dejo un ejemplo básico pero claro de lo que necesitas.

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <title>Dinamicos</title>
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/validationEngine.jquery.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/jquery.validationEngine.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/languages/jquery.validationEngine-es.js"></script>
  <style>
    .top-buffer {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container ">
    <div class="row-fluid top-buffer">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 text-center">
        <form id="miform" method="post" name="miform" action="guarda.php">
          <table id="tblprod" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th># Registro</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>
                  <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                    <input class="form-control validate[required]" name="nombre[]" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                    <input class="form-control validate[required]" name="apellido[]" />
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <button id="btnadd" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar Nuevo</button>
          <button id="btnsubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      var count = 1;
      jQuery("#miform").validationEngine({
        promptPosition: "centerRight:0,-5"
      });

      $(document).on("click", "#btnadd", function(event) {
        count++;
        $('#tblprod tr:last').after('<tr><td>' + count + '</td><td><div class="form-group col-lg-4"><input class="form-control validate[required]" name=" nombre[]" /></div><div class="form-group col-lg-4"><input class="form-control validate[required]" name="apellido[]" /></div></td></tr>');
        event.preventDefault();

      });

    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

**guarda.php**

```
<?php

foreach (array_keys($_POST['nombre']) as $key) {
  $nombre = $_POST['nombre'][$key];
  $apellido = $_POST['apellido'][$key];

  echo "Nombre: $nombre"."<br>"."Apellido: $apellido"."<br>";
}


?>
```

Con ese ejemplo podras resolver tus dudas, te recuerdo que yo solo imprimi el resultado, pero tu solo haces la query de insert y listo.

> ACTUALIZACION

Hola, aqui te muestro como hacer el insert segun el ejemplo expuesto anteriormente, para que puedas entender mucho mejor, todo el codigo acabo de hacerlo y esta completamente funcional:

**guarda.php**

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "dbtest");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

foreach (array_keys($_POST['nombre']) as $key) {
  $nombre = $_POST['nombre'][$key];
  $apellido = $_POST['apellido'][$key];

  echo "Nombre: $nombre"."<br>"."Apellido: $apellido"."<br>";

  $query = "INSERT INTO usuario VALUES (NULL, '$nombre', '$apellido')";
$mysqli->query($query);
}


?>
```

Quedo atento

Comment: hola ByGroxD- anteriormente de esa manera lo inicie, pero se me complicó porque cada imput padre (pregunta), tiene campos hijo (opciones) que tambien se agregan dinamicamente, así que tuve que agrerar una variable para asignarme numeracion a los campos padre (preguntas), ya que de esa manera puedo indicarle a cada hijo a que grupo de preguntas pertenece, sino al momento de agregar una opcion a una segunda pregunta siempre la agregaba en la primera de la misma forma la momento de eliminar preguntas o una opcion espesifica, pero muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo

Comment: Disculpame mas o menos te logro entender, sin embargo te invito a compartir este comentario en tu Pregunta principal y si lo reformateas de manera mas clara (si es posible) hazlo sera de mucha utilidad para poderte ayudar, tan pronto lo hagas me comentas, asi re construyo el codigo.

Comment: por cierto si puedes y es posible pasame tu codigo actual (formulario y tu archivo php) en un zip, para revisar de manera detallada y darte un ejemplo acorde a tu proyecto

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fx2f4ipqipoifj0/formulario_dinamico.rar?dl=0 aqui tengo alojado el ejemplo gracias

Comment: Vale, tan pronto llegue a casa reviso

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo :D

Comment: ya lo revise y la verdad no es dificil hacerlo, se tiene que crear otro campo en tu tabla, que se llame por ejemplo id_pregunta supongo que en tu tabla de opciones(respuestas) tienes algo como (id,respuesta, valor) en esa creas otro campo que se llame id_pregunta, en el html haces lo siguiente, en el espacio donde le das click y te genera dos input uno que se llama respuesta y valor, puedes agregar otro input con el name="id_pregunta[]" este tendra un value="NOMBRE DE LA PREGUNTA",

Comment: eso lo puedes hacer con Jquery, y pues a ese input le pones un Style="display: none;" para que no se vea, pero que se cargue en el value el nombre de la pregunta, asi cuando vayas a imprimir una pregunta es cuestion de llamarlos con foreach con la condicional cuando el id_pregunta == pregunta, yo lo haria pero pues soy un poco malo con jquery y javascript

Comment: Me acabas de dar una muy buena idea muchas gracias me ha servido tu comentario :D

Comment: vale, =D la idea era esa, espero lo puedas solucionar cualquier cosa puedes seguir modificando tu pregunta o hacer otra, que pena de verdad no poderte ayudar mas pero soy muy limitado en cuanto a javascript y sus librerias

Comment: muchas gracias, muy buen codigo.