# Recoger parámetros de formulario dinámico con django

Tags: javascript, django

estoy generando varios input text dinámicamente con Javascrip, los datos de estos inputs los guardo en una IndexedDB pero una vez que tengo varios datos ya almacenados quisiera pasarlos a mi modelo en django y guardarlos en un modelo que está relacionado con otro como podría hacerlo. Básicamente tengo el mismo problema que en esta pregunta ([guardar datos de formulario dinamico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90489/guardar-datos-de-formulario-dinamico)) pero ellos recogen los datos con php y yo necesito hacerlo con python, usando django. Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Has leído acerca de los [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/#module-django.forms.formsets)?

Comment: Soy nuevo en todo esto de django a penas estoy comenzando lo buscaré muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si deseas coger los datos directamente de los inputs, crea una un m'etodo en  `views.py`  el cual sirva para leer los datos de cada input, los cuales los obtendras por el m'etodo  `POST`  y seleccionando por el atributo  `name`, primero configura `url.py` con la url de la p'agina donde se crean los inputs, la vista seria algo asi:

> `def get_data(request):
>      if request.method == 'POST':
>          data_1 = request.POST.get('nombre_del_input1')
>          data_2 = request.POST.get('nombre_del_input2')
>      return  data_1, data_2`

la url:

`url(r'^my_url$/', 'my_app.views.get_data')`

y el html:

`input name="nombre_input1"
input name="nombre_input2"`

despues que tengas todos los datos se lo envias al modelo que necesitas, espero te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias lo pruebo y comento saludos