# Enviar formulario con varios inputs con diferente name en PHP (Registros multiples)

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tardes tengo la siguiente duda y es que tengo un formulario donde ingreso unos datos y con un boton vuelvo a generar los mismos inputs pero cambia el name, ejemplo:

Input numero del empleado: numemp_1

Input numero del empleado 2: numemp_2

**Imagen de referencia:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que se quiere lograr es hacer el registro simultaneo de toda esta informacion, pero no tengp una idea clara de como enviar el POST de los inputs.

Comment: Esto responde a tu pregunta? [Guardar datos de formularios dinamicos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90489/guardar-datos-de-formulario-dinamico)

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo convirtiendo tus campos *nombre*,... como arrays en lugar de valores al enviar el formulario.

En tus campos input *número de empleado* debes agregar corchetes en tu atributo name, así:

```
name="nombre_empleado[]"
```

Después en el archivo PHP donde recibas los datos, puedes recogerlos así:

```
<?php
...

$nombre_empleados = $_POST['nombre_empleado'];
...
```

Pero deberás hacer esto mismo con todos los campos (inputs) que desees recoger como arrays (imagino que todos).

Al final tendrás una serie de arrays que agrupan la información de los distintos usuarios a través del índice de los mismos.

Comment: Gracias de esta manera lo hice.